# Advert a Facebook Page Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, ads

When I go to **Create advert**, then **App installation**, the given list doesn't contains that application I would advert. When I start to write the App-s name it appear, but when I choose it I get the following message:
It is a Page Tab so I don't know what more platform needed to create an advert to this App, or what is wrong with settings?
**There are no platforms available for advertising this application. You can choose a different one or learn how to add platforms to your application.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about FB advertising platform, not programming/development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If app is a like gate and it's platform is only page tab, not possible to create advert on it.